# Last row in CSS grid doesnt fit into my html

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm developing an Electron app to **scrape** a cacti server, The main **scraping** parts works fine but I've got confused about the UI.
The problem is that in my last row buttons just seems to not getting fit inside html(or body, my html is terrible, sorry for that). I know a little bit about CSS and HTML and after lots of searching here is my UI related code:

```css
html {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Ubuntu', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: auto;
    font-weight: bold;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.container{
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template: 250px minmax(10px, 1fr) 40px / auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.grid-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, auto);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    /* grid-template-columns: auto; */
}
.grid-container > div{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto ;
    /* grid-template-columns: repeate(2, auto); */
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1.6fr;
}

label{
    margin-right: 15px;
    user-select: none;
}

.btn-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 30% auto 30%;
    /* padding-bottom: 50px; */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

input {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Ubuntu', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 3px solid #e78616;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
}


button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    outline: none;
}
button:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fd0101;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
input:hover{
    cursor: text;
}

input.glow {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 31px 9px #ff4da665;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 31px 9px #ff4da665;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 9px #ff4da665;
    border-radius: 10px;
    appearance: none;
}

label.glow {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000;
    text-shadow: 3px 0px 20px #ff188b;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div id="ip_input" class="inner-grid-container">
        <label for="ip_input_entry_point">Cacti Server IP:</label>
        <input type="text" id="ip_input_entry_point" minlength="7" maxlength="15" size="15" placeholder="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
          pattern="^((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$">
      </div>
      <div id="port_input" class="inner-grid-container">
        <label for="port_input_entry_point">Cacti Server Port:</label>
        <input type="port" id="port_input_entry_point" minlength="2" maxlength="5" size="15" placeholder="xx">
      </div>
      <div id="user_input" class="inner-grid-container">
        <label for="user_input_entry_point">Cacti Server User:</label>
        <input type="text" id="user_input_entry_point" minlength="1" maxlength="15" size="15" placeholder="username">
      </div>
      <div id="password_input" class="inner-grid-container">
        <label for="password_input_entry_point">Cacti Server Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password_input_entry_point" minlength="7" maxlength="15" size="15"
          placeholder="You'r login password">
      </div>
      <div id="begin_input" class="inner-grid-container">
        <label for="begin_input_entry_point">From Date:</label>
        <input type="text" id="begin_input_entry_point" class="begin_date" placeholder="YYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS">
      </div>
      <div id="finish_input" class="inner-grid-container">
        <label for="finish_input_entry_point">To Date:</label>
        <input type="text" id="finish_input_entry_point" class="finish_date" placeholder="YYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="visibility: hidden">Junky TEXT</div>
    <div class="btn-container">
      <button class="button" id="run-btn">Run</button>
      <div></div>
      <button class="button" id="reset-btn">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I need a responsive UI, so I added an extra div between inputs and buttons, and I set auto for it so it could grow and shrink, but what really bothers me is that I cant make a distance between buttons and the bottom of page, something like padding-bottom or margin-bottom doesnt work and I dont know why.

Comment: Is there any problem to have link to codepen in quuestions that Im unaware about?
I've just noticed that my link to codepen has been edited

Comment: The problem is that often the code from external pages disappears and this entry becomes useless. Leaving the code here is the certainty that someone going in after some time will have the whole code and question.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

to your **container** class.

I personally use `display: flex` for most of my CSS because it is easier to manipulate. If you'd like to know more about it you can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

Comment: I've searched a lot about flex and grid, and after all I think grid is a better option in this case, because flex is for one dimensional context and grid for 2D, and I need columns in some of my rows, but thanks for your answer, anyway I think adding `height: 90%` to my .container would solve the problem, but I really need to know the source of my problem